# Advanced search terms in the Semi-automatic Classification plugin

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, scp

**Background:**

At QGIS 3.18.1, I can successfully download Sentinel Level-1C imagery by entering the granule that covers my area of interest (10UGU) in the *Advanced search* box.

Now I would like to download Level-2A imagery for the same granule.

The [Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin documentation](https://readthedocs.org/projects/semiautomaticclassificationmanual/downloads/pdf/latest/) states on page 48:

> "... some services (e.g. Sentinel-2) allows for entering search
> parameters; for instance, it is possible to enter the name of a
> granule (e.g. 33TTG) without defining a search area in order to get
> the results of that granule; ***Sentinel-2 level 2A can be filtered
> entering S2A_MSIL2A*;***" [my emphasis].

What I want to do now is have *two* search parameters in the Advanced search box, one for the granule (`10UGU`), and the other for the Level-2A imagery (`S2A_MSIL2A*;`).

**Problem:**

Whenever I add the two parameters in the Advanced search box, and then click the *Find* button to search for available imagery, SCP responds with the statement **Information [23] Define a search area** as shown here:

[image]

I have tried adding the two parameters in every combination that I can think of: placing one before the other, separating them with commas, semicolons, spaces, etc.  In every case, SCP responds with the error shown in the screenshot above.

**Question:**

How do I add multiple search parameters to the Advanced search box?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TL;TR:**
According to the source code, you cannot search multiple parameters without defining a search area (`UL` and `LR`).

---

Explanation based-on [the source code](https://github.com/semiautomaticgit/SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin/blob/80d8dcc04b307196e0302c7168af000b2333f536/maininterface/downloadproducts.py#L1431) shown in the image below:

1. The plugin, first, separates the `Advanced search` text by `;`.
2. If it doesn't contain `;`, it tries to separate by `,`. So, it doesn't matter which character you use to separate the parameters, but use just one, `,` or `;`.
3. It creates a rectangle using `UL` and `LR` coordinates. In your case (no search area), it throws an error because you don't specify a search area. So, the script jumps to `except` block.
4. If there is one parameter, no problem. The script continues running after `except` block and searches the products.
5. **If there are multiple parameters**, it goes to `else` and shows `Define a search area` message.
6. And it ends the execution of the process. `return` means that.

In a nutshell, you have to specify a search area for multiple parameters.

[image]

Comment: Interesting!  The whole purpose for including a granule in the Advanced Search box is to *avoid* having to insert insert UL and LR coordinates.  Nice job of reviewing the code!